# Check boxes will not stay loaded on page after other events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, dom

**Objective**: I have a list of checkboxes that are loaded onto the HTML DOM via JSON and javascript. The checkbox buttons will load onto the page fine but if I use my other function `uncheckAllCities()`, all of the buttons will disappear from the display, not uncheck them. I am not sure why. It happens for several other actions such as when I ask it to do the calculations the check buttons go missing. Perhaps it has to do with how I added the checkboxes from the JSON to begin with.
Any ideas why the buttons disappear from view?
The following functions generate the checkboxes...

```
function buildCheckBoxes() {
    JSONCities = [ //Build checkbox controls to choose which cities get APIs      
        {
            "CityName": "Bellaire",
            "LatLong": "47.1200,-88.4600",
            "index": "a",
            "checked": "checked"
        }, ...(more JSON code)...
    },
];
//Form a list of checkboxes from JSON
for (j = 0; j < JSONCities.length; j++) //Need to learn if value may be set in checkbox to return, not just true and false checked
{
    loadChk = '<input class="checkboxes_class" type="checkbox" name="checkbox-v-2' + JSONCities[j].index + '" value="' + JSONCities[j].LatLong + '" id="checkbox-v-2' + JSONCities[j].index + '"' + JSONCities[j].checked + '>' + " " + '<label for="checkbox-v-2' + JSONCities[j].index + '">' + JSONCities[j].CityName + '</label>';
    locCheckBtn += loadChk;
}
$('#loc1').html(locCheckBtn); // update HTML DOM    
}


$(document).ready(function() {
    //prepare checkbox buttons on page load.
    buildCheckBoxes();
});

function uncheckAllCities() { //stackoverflow.com/questions/14110169/check-uncheck-the-array-of-checkboxes
    document.getElementsByClassName("checkboxes_class").checked = false;
}
```

Comment: Could you create a short [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) (or upload a live demo elsewhere) that shows this behaviour? There doesn't seems to be something obviously wrong with this code, but maybe we can see something odd in a live demo.

Comment: Sure it will take a minute. How do you share it on jsfiddle with public eyes? I tried before and it did not work but I will try again. There may be a few bugs. As it it runs once a session.

Comment: No worries! It didn't fully function in the fiddle for me, but I managed to play around with it a bit. I haven't been able to trigger the bug, but I did find an error in your `uncheckAllCities` function that *may* have caused/helped the bug: `document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array of elements, not a single one. So instead of adding `checked = false` to the result of it you should loop over the array and set `checked = false` to each item in the array.

Comment: This should work if you place it into your browser or some editor program. For some reason the jsfiddle is not loading the buttons but it is the exact code I use for my own and it works. https://jsfiddle.net/safron6/apm1L6gr/

Comment: Thank you for noticing that.

Comment: How about this: `function uncheckAllCities(){  //stackoverflow.com/questions/14110169/check-uncheck-the-array-of-checkboxes
locCheckBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName("checkboxes_class");
    $.each(locCheckBoxes, function(g, checked) {

        if (locCheckBoxes[g].checked) {
         document.getElementsByClassName("checkboxes_class").checked = false;
        }
        locCheckBoxes = [];
    });
    
    document.getElementsByClassName("checkboxes_class").checked = false;
  }`

Comment: That also won't work because you're still assigning `checked` to the result of `document.getElementsByClassName`. However, I completely missed that you're using jQuery so you can make it a lot simpler for yourself: `$(".checboxes_class").prop("checked", false)` is all you need. It works like this: `$(".checkboxes_class")` selects all elements with the `checkboxes_class` but "wraps" them in a jQuery object. That wrapped object allows you to set the checked property for all elements at the same time with `.prop("checked", false)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77657/discussion-between-tiddo-and-safron6).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Playing around with your code I found two problems:

1. I already mentioned this in a comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection, not an element, so you should loop over it and set `checked = false` to each individual element.
2. By default all html buttons are submit-buttons. Therefore as soon as you click any button the form will be submitted, resulting in the page being refreshed. If you add the `type="button"` attribute to each button the form won't be submitted when you click on them (e.g. `<button type="button">click here!</button>`). (Small sidenote: I'm not really sure why the checkboxes don't load after the form has been submitted, but setting the `type` to `button` should at least solve your problem so I didn't investigate that any further)

Comment: But will these be check buttons? How will I know if it is selected? The type makes these checkboxes right?

Comment: It looks like I have successfully set the values to false. In order to use buttons I would have to set a background table to store the selected values but that may not be obvious to the user unless I use CSS to modify the button to show it is set.

Comment: This is the answer but the checkboxes deselect cities function bug is unresolved.